# ECS Task placement strategy not respecting Terraform file

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs, terraform-provider-aws

I'm investigating the reason why ECS task placement has not worked as intended. There are 2 services in the ECS cluster:

1. service-a has one task
2. service-b has two tasks

There are two services, and for service A,
It is set up to launch one task per instance.

For service B, it is configured to evenly distribute across availability zones and deploy to each instance, but it seems like it's not working properly.

I've set the ecs module as following :

```
  dynamic "ordered_placement_strategy" {
    for_each = var.scheduling_strategy == "REPLICA" ? [1] : []
    content {
      type  = "spread"
      field = "attribute:ecs.availability-zone"
     }
   }

  dynamic "ordered_placement_strategy" {
    for_each = var.scheduling_strategy == "REPLICA" ? [1] : []
    content {
      type  = "spread"
      field = "instanceId"
     }
   }
```

But after the cluster has set, it seems that the tasks from service-b is set on one instance. (e.g, AZ-B in one instance)

```
{
  "ServiceName": "service-a",
  "PlacementStrategy": [
    {
      "type": "spread",
      "field": "attribute:ecs.availability-zone"
    },
    {
      "type": "spread",
      "field": "instanceId"
    }
  ]
}
{
  "TaskArn": "arn:aws:ecs:ap-northeast-2:****:task/service-a/****",
  "TaskDefinition": "arn:aws:ecs:ap-northeast-2:****:task-definition/service-a-throttler:44",
  "AvailabilityZone": "ap-northeast-2a",
  "EC2InstanceId": "i-****"
}
{
  "ServiceName": "service-b",
  "PlacementStrategy": [
    {
      "type": "spread",
      "field": "attribute:ecs.availability-zone"
    },
    {
      "type": "spread",
      "field": "instanceId"
    }
  ]
}
{
  "TaskArn": "arn:aws:ecs:ap-northeast-2:****:task/service-b/****",
  "TaskDefinition": "arn:aws:ecs:ap-northeast-2:****:task-definition/service-b-api:36",
  "AvailabilityZone": "ap-northeast-2b",
  "EC2InstanceId": "i-****"
}
{
  "TaskArn": "arn:aws:ecs:ap-northeast-2:****:task/service-b/****",
  "TaskDefinition": "arn:aws:ecs:ap-northeast-2:****:task-definition/service-b-api:36",
  "AvailabilityZone": "ap-northeast-2b",
  "EC2InstanceId": "i-****"
}
```

If you have any idea, please let me know.

Comment: It's unclear from your question what the expected behavior is. Please edit your question to describe in more detail what you expected to happen, and what is actually  happening. It would help if you showed enough of the Terraform code that we could actually see what is being applied. As it is you show some dynamic code with a condition in it, and you don't provide any information on what the condition should be evaluating to.

Comment: Sorry, my bad.

The information following is as I mentioned, there are two services, 
and for service A, it is set up to launch one task per instance. 

For service B, it is configured to evenly distribute across availability zones and deploy to each instance, but it seems like it's not working properly, so I asked. 
This information came from querying with AWS CLI commands.

Comment: The way your condition is written in both of your `dynamic` blocks, if the `var.scheduling_strategy` is `"REPLICA"` then an `ordered_placement_strategy` block will be created, otherwise **nothing** will be created. Your question is also still unclear because you don't explain where that JSON data at the end of your question comes from. Is that the output from an AWS CLI command or something?